# How to locate TYPO3 Binary (typo3)

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-11.x

As of TYPO3 11 LTS the `typo3` binary isn't located in `sysext/core/bin/` anymore, at least not in composer mode, so I need to get a new way to locate the `bin-dir` from composer in composer mode.

Should I use the composer/composer package to parse that? I need the `root` composer and not the one for the TYPO3 Crawler.

```php
if (TYPO3_COMPOSER_MODE) {
    // How to find the composer-bin dir?      
} else {
    $typo3BinaryPath = ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('core') . 'bin/';
}
```

Any suggestions on how to deal with this? An option could be to add it as a setting, so it's part of the extension settings.

Comment: What I would be interested in is, why you need this information at all.

Comment: I do that to be able to execute the processQueue command. 

I calculate this in the TYPO3 BE. 

"/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/typo3 crawler:processQueue"

I just got this suggestion which might be a better option. https://github.com/tomasnorre/crawler/issues/813

Will need to check out how that works.

Answer (score 3):

I went for this solution. But would be happy to hear about other/better solutions.

```php
private function getComposerBinPath(): string
{
    $composerRootPath = Environment::getComposerRootPath();
    $composerJson = json_decode(file_get_contents($composerRootPath . '/composer.json'), true);
    $binDir = $composerJson['config']['bin-dir'] ?? 'vendor/bin';
    return $composerRootPath . '/' . $binDir . '/';
}
```

This is the implementation in the TYPO3 Core for the Scheduler extension.

https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/8a9c80b9d85ef986f5f369f1744fc26a6b607dda/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Controller/SchedulerModuleController.php#L402